# Enter text into the text box of another windows application using Java.`

Tags: java, windows

I have a windows application (say application XYZ) that has a text box in it. My goal is to create a Java application that will enter text into the app XYZ. This has to be done without needing XYZ to be visible on the screen(could be behind an application and should still work). What library or tool should I use to acheive this. I heard about screen **scraping** but I think it won't work with this.

NOTE : I don't have access to the source code of XYZ.

Comment: Not possible. You can do it in the Windows API directly, but not from Java.

Comment: Windows API is very new to me. Is it something to be used in C or C++? If so can you point me in the right direction. It would help me a lot.